# How to replace one color in a image with another one?

Tags: colors, pixel, graphicsmagick

I've this image:

[image]

Its background (and only) color is "#687a40" but want to change it for the color "#9ea09a" (a light grey).

I've tried with this command...:

```
gm convert photo.png -fuzz 0% -fill "#9ea09a" -opaque "#678a40" photoGREY.png
```

...but I've not seen any effect on the image. I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but GM's documentation is not very friendly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image has an alpha channel, so you need:

```
gm convert input.png -fill "#9ea09a" -opaque "#687a40ff" result.png
```